# Python-equivalent string formatting with dictionary in Perl with hashes

Tags: perl, hash, dictionary, string-formatting

I love the way Python can format a string with a dictionary:

```
print "%(key1)s and %(key2)s" % aDictObj
```

I want to achieve the same thing in Perl with hashes. Is there any snippet or small library to do so?

#### EDIT:

Thanks for trying this answer. As for me, I came out with a short piece of code:

```
sub dict_replace
{
    my ($tempStr, $tempHash) = @_;
    my $key;

    foreach $key (sort keys %$tempHash) {
        my $tmpTmp = $tempHash->{$key};
        $tempStr =~ s/%\($key\)s/$tmpTmp/g;
    }

    return $tempStr;
}
```

It just works. This is not as feature-complete as Python string-formatting with a dictionary but I'd like to improve on that.

Comment: Are you looking for Text::Template?   http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Text::Template

Comment: Thanks David. However, it isn't as elegant as Python.

Comment: Are you, then, suggesting something like this?  `%aDictObj = ( definitions => here ); print "$_->{key1}s and $_->{key2}s" for \%aDictObj;`

Comment: What about Data::Dumper?  http://search.cpan.org/~smueller/Data-Dumper-2.131/Dumper.pm

Comment: Thanks Spock. This is not what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the python documentation:

> The effect is similar to the using sprintf() in the C language.

So this is a solution using [`printf`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/printf.html) or [`sprintf`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sprintf.html)

```
my @ordered_list_of_values_to_print = qw(key1 key2);
printf '%s and %s', @ordered_list_of_values_to_print;
```

There is also a new module which does it using named parameters:

```
use Text::sprintfn;
my %dict = (key1 => 'foo', key2 => 'bar');
printfn '%(key1)s and %(key2)s', \%dict;
```

Comment: formatting with a dictionary is completely different from the C printf(). it allows to specify which argument to use when building the string based on its name, and not based on its position in the argument list.

Comment: `cpan Text::sprintfn` doesn't work: *Cannot install Text::sprintfn, don't know what it is.*

Comment: J.F. Sebastian, there's an indexing screwup or something. Install using the more qualified notation `SHARYANTO/Text-sprintfn-0.03.tar.gz`.

Answer (score 4):

You could write it as:

```
say format_map '{$key1} and {$key2}', \%aDictObj
```

If you define:

```
sub format_map($$) {
 my ($s, $h) = @_;
 Text::Template::fill_in_string($s, HASH=>$h);
}
```

It is a direct equivalent of `"{key1} and {key2}".format_map(aDictObj)` in Python.

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure what's wrong with string interpolation here.

```
print "$aDictObj{key1} and $aDictObj{key2}\n";
```

Comment: Perl string interpolation is not as flexible as Python string-fomatting with a dictionary.

Comment: `print "%(key1)s and %(key2)s" % aDictObj` and `print "$aDictObj{key1} and $aDictObj{key}"` are practically the same. How is the Python version more flexible?

Comment: @flesk: Viet might mean that you could use width,precision specifiers, etc in Python version.

Comment: Then you're back to printf(). Still NBD.