# authoritative regular expression for (s)printf FORMAT string

Tags: regex, perl, printf

I would like to answer [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7950530/python-equivalent-string-formatting-with-dictionary-in-perl-with-hashes) with

To get all of Perl's fancy formatting **and** keyed access to hash data, you
need a (better version of this) function:

```
# sprintfx(FORMAT, HASHREF) - like sprintf(FORMAT, LIST) but accepts
# "%<key>$<tail>" instead of "%<index>$<tail>" in FORMAT to access the
# values of HASHREF according to <key>. Fancy formatting is done by
# passing '%<tail>', <corresponding value> to sprintf.
sub sprintfx {
  my ($f, $rh) = @_;
  $f =~ s/
     (%%)               # $1: '%%' for '%'
     |                  # OR
     %                  # start format
     (\w+)              # $2: a key to access the HASHREF
     \$                 # end key/index
     (                  # $3: a valid FORMAT tail
                        #   'everything' upto the type letter
        [^BDEFGOUXbcdefginosux]*
                        #   the type letter ('p' removed; no 'next' pos for storage)
         [BDEFGOUXbcdefginosux]
     )
    /$1 ? '%'                           # got '%%', replace with '%'
        : sprintf( '%' . $3, $rh->{$2}) # else, apply sprintf
    /xge;
  return $f;
}
```

but I'm ashamed of the risky/brute force approach to capturing the format string's 'tail'.

So: Is there a regular expression for the FORMAT string that you can trust?

Comment: Are you aware that `%%` is not a special case in `sprintf`? For instance `sprintf('%2%')` would produce the string `' %'`.

Answer (score 1):

The acceptable format is pretty well speced out in [`perldoc -f sprintf`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?perlfunc#sprintf). Between the `'%'` and the format letter, you can have:

```
     (\d+\$)?         # format parameter index (though this is probably
                      # incompatible with the dictionary feature)

     [ +0#-]*         # flags

     (\*?v)?          # vector flag

     \d*              # minimum width

     (\.\d+|\.\*)?    # precision or maximum width

     (ll|[lhqL])?     # size
```

Comment: The problem is that some modifiers only apply to some format specifiers.

Comment: The OP is just passing the format tokens to the builtin `sprintf`, not trying to reimplement `sprintf`. If the input contains an invalid sequence, it will be handled the same was Perl's `sprintf` would handle it, which might be the desired behavior.

Comment: e.g., What should the output of `sprintfx "%(abc)vs",{abc=>"def"};` be? Should it be `%(abc)vs` or is it acceptable for it to be `%vs`?

Answer (score 1):

If you're asking how to do it exactly like Perl, then consult what Perl does.

[Perl_sv_vcatpvfn](http://perl5.git.perl.org/perl.git/blob/dc281e6088d189558b79a5121119b7196c8b3db0:/sv.c#l9985) is `sprintf` format parser and evaluator. (Link to 5.14.2's implementation.)